# LDAP context search in Java provides no results, even when searching on value known to be there

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I've done a lot of Googling and seen several similar answers on this site, but nothing is working for me.

I have been trying to do a search of ActiveDirectory using LDAP.  The search runs okay, but it never returns results. I am searching on userPrincipalName, and this user absolutely exists in ActiveDirectory.

```
String securityPrincipal;
    securityPrincipal = "{0}@" +"ourcompany";
    securityPrincipal = MessageFormat.format(securityPrincipal, username);

    Hashtable<String,Object> env = new Hashtable<>();

    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://OURCOMPANY:636");
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    //Internal and external the same
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, securityPrincipal);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    env.put(Context.REFERRAL,"follow");

    boolean success;
    LdapContext ldapCtx = null;
    try {
        ldapCtx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
        success = true;
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        success = false;
if(ldapCtx != null){
doSearch(ldapCtx)
}

private static final void doSearch(LdapContext ctx) throws NamingException{
        NamingEnumeration results = null;
        String domain = "DC=ourcompany,DC=com";
    String organizationalUnit = "ou=external";

    String searchUser;
    searchUser = "cdanvers@ourcompany.com";
    try {
        DirContext schema = ctx.getSchema("");

        String[] returning = {"userPrincipalName"};
        SearchControls ctrls = new SearchControls();
        ctrls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        ctrls.setReturningAttributes(returning);
        Attributes attributes = new BasicAttributes(true);
        attributes.put("userPrincipalName",searchUser);

         results = ctx.search(organizationalUnit +"," +domain,attributes);

        while (results.hasMoreElements()){
            System.out.println("...");
        }


        System.out.println(results.hasMore());


    }catch (NamingException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        results.close();
    }
```

In addition to what is above, I've tried:

- Using this type of search: `results = ctx.search(organizationalUnit +"," +domain,"(& (userPrincipalName=" +searchUser +"))",ctrls);`
- Using this type of search: `results = ctx.search(domain,"(& (userPrincipalName=" +searchUser +"))",ctrls);`
- Passing null to `ctrls.setReturningAttributes()`
- `ctrls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.OBJECT_SCOPE);`

This should be returning results.  Results is not null, but results.entries() is empty.

Comment: Do you have proper permissions?
I would suggest you utilize a known good ldap tool such as ldapsearch or http://directory.apache.org/studio/ to test your search

Comment: I'll try that.  I think I have proper permissions, but not sure.  I have suspected that some of my problems have been permissions related, but I haven't figured out how to ascertain that for sure.

Comment: I downloaded Apache Directory Studio like you suggested.  It's proven a valuable tool.  I couldn't figure out my issue, but while trying I realized that I don't think I need to.  I started trying to implement search to learn LDAP and my real goal was writing data to it.  Dunno why it took me so long to realize that.

My permissions are okay.  The issue is not really resolved, but I think it's become a non-issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since AD is a Microsoft tool, its responses are not driven to help. Are driven to be impossible to understand and to require a payed support. Here a response sample if you are sending something that AD don't understand or support. It is so complex to figure out the error reason/cause.

```
[LDAP: error code 16 - 000016515: LdapErr: DSID-066675D87, data 0, v64xyz]
```

### Context object location is millimeter

You need to find the exact **context object** or **location** in which your user exist.

[image]

image source: https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101405&seqNum=7

**option #1**

What helped me was to access to the AD Admin GUI and put the mouse over the user and then a popup will appear with the exact context of this object. Also at the top of ui appear the required context. If user don't exist, create a new one.

[image]

**option #2**

Also you can obtain the same value using the **Distinguished** attribute, editing the user as Admin

[image]

Source: https://windowstechno.com/how-to-check-the-distinguished-name-dn/

### Tip

Just to try, you could design a request with these values:

| Field | Sample Value |
| --- | --- |
| objectLocation | OU=users,DC=foo,DC=bar,etc=wtf |
| searchQuery | (mail=jane.doe@foo.com) |

And I use these values in my code:

```java
LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(environment, null);
ctx.setRequestControls(null);
NamingEnumeration<?> searchResultEnum =
  ctx.search(objectLocation, searchQuery, getSimpleSearchControls());
```

This will help you to try dozens of combinations until you find the exact **objectLocation**